# Can I defeat an opponent with their own commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-commander-damage

I know that if I gain control of my opponent's commander, it won't lose the status of commander. How is the commander damage calculated in this case? Can I do the 21 commander damage with the stolen commander to win the game? Does the damage add to the damage of my own commander?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can make a player lose by dealing 21 total damage to them with their own commander. (If it keeps getting stolen by yourself or others, a cumulative total 21 damage from their own commander will make them lose.)

The rule, from mtgcommander.net's [Rules — Play section](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php), is:

> 11. If a player has been dealt 21 points of combat damage by a particular Commander during the game, that player loses a game.

That is any one specific commander card, including their own. Commander damage from different commander cards doesn't count together: if you've successfully stolen every commander on the board and dealt 20 damage with each of them to one opponent, they *still* haven't lost to commander damage.

Also, commander damage never makes anyone *win* directly, it only makes players lose. You'll only win if them losing made you win, e.g. they were your only opponent.

Comment: If you've dealt 20 damage with 4 or 5 different commanders, most decks will have lost by then, not due to commander damage, but due to being dealt 80-100 damage.